# JAX-WS dependencies causing tomcat Failed to scan File error

Tags: tomcat, soap, jax-ws

I've just started developing a SOAP web service for an assignment on Windows 10 using Eclipse Mars2 4.5.2 and Tomcat 8.0.35. The Tomcat server starts fine but when I copy the JAX-WS dependency jars into the `tomcat/lib` folder the server produces many "File not found" exceptions for other random jar files:

> May 27, 2016 3:54:09 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
>   WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/H:/Dev/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/lib/txw2-2.2.10-b140802.1033.jar] from classloader hierarchy
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: H:\Dev\apache-tomcat-8.0.35\lib\txw2-2.2.10-b140802.1033.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)

I have tried all the JAX-WS jars and then just the ones that are required and neither works.

If anyone has experienced this issue before and knows how to solve it any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this too on Linux Mint when when upgrading to a newer Tomcat release (8.0.36 from 8.0.33).  The solution was to read the JAX-WS documentation and follow the directions for installing it :-)

First, make certain your CATALINA_HOME environment variable is set correctly.  Now, instead of copying the JAX-WS jar files into Tomcat's lib (remove them if you alread have), perform the following:

```
cd {extracted jaxws-ri directory}
ant install
ant install-api
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem. My solution is:

1. Delete the jar file and its directory.
2. Execute the `'mvn clean -Dmaven.test.skip=true install'` command.
3. Finally execute maven update the project, and restart the tomcat.

Hope this helps you.